# Linux find command - find files based on inode and device?

Tags: filesystem, find, inode, stat

I want to find the files with a given inode number. Using find with `-inum` is not entirely helpfull as its listing files with the inode number from every file system/device. How to confine this search to a particular device/fs?

Below is not helpfull -

```
$ sudo find / -inum 2
/
/dev
/dev/shm
/dev/pts/ptmx
/sys/kernel/debug/acpi
/sys/fs
/sys/fs/cgroup
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/cgroup.procs
/sys/fs/cgroup/pids/cgroup.procs
/sys/fs/cgroup/rdma/cgroup.procs
/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/cgroup.procs
/sys/fs/cgroup/devices/cgroup.procs
/sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/cgroup.procs
/sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event/cgroup.procs
/sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/cgroup.procs
/sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb/cgroup.procs
/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/cgroup.procs
/sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio/cgroup.procs
/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/cgroup.procs
/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/cgroup.procs
/run
/run/user/1000
find: ‘/run/user/1000/doc’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
/run/user/125
find: ‘/run/user/125/gvfs’: Permission denied
/run/lock
/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/meta/snap.yaml
/snap/snapd/8790/bin/fc-cache-v6
/snap/snapd/8542/bin/fc-cache-v6
/snap/tusk/29/LICENSES.chromium.html
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/bin/bunzip2
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/bin/bzcat
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/bin/bzip2
/snap/snap-store/467/autostart/setup-autostart
/snap/core18/1885/bin
/snap/core18/1880/bin
/snap/jdownloader2/10/etc/X11
/snap/jdownloader2/12/etc/X11
/snap/core/9804/bin/bash
/proc/fs/nfsd/exports
/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/status
```

#### Below confirms that above listed files are from various devices

```
/etc$ stat /dev/shm /dev /dev/pts/ptmx 
  File: /dev/shm
  Size: 80          Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 1ah/26d Inode: 2           Links: 2
Access: (1777/drwxrwxrwt)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2020-09-03 14:01:23.968171064 +0530
Modify: 2020-09-03 14:01:53.055049949 +0530
Change: 2020-09-03 14:01:53.055049949 +0530
 Birth: -
  File: /dev
  Size: 4920        Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 6h/6d   Inode: 2           Links: 23
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2020-09-03 11:24:49.787963116 +0530
Modify: 2020-09-03 11:20:16.282767765 +0530
Change: 2020-09-03 11:20:16.282767765 +0530
 Birth: -
  File: /dev/pts/ptmx
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 1024   character special file
Device: 18h/24d Inode: 2           Links: 1     Device type: 5,2
Access: (0000/c---------)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2020-09-03 10:18:19.587999997 +0530
Modify: 2020-09-03 10:18:19.587999997 +0530
Change: 2020-09-03 10:18:19.587999997 +0530
 Birth: -
```

Comment: Crossposted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/607664/linux-find-command-find-files-based-on-inode-and-device

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use `sudo debugfs -R 'ncheck {inode}' /dev/{device} 2>/dev/null` It should only list the files for that device.

As you did not specify the filesystem: this only works on ext and I assumed you used the default.

Answer (score -2):

From `man find`:

> ```
>    -mount Don't descend directories on other filesystems.
>           An alternate name for -xdev, for compatibility with
>           some other versions of find.
> ```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about inodes.

Comment: The original command answered that; it contained ```-inum``` parameter to ```find```. The OP only complained that it finds files with the specfied inode on all filesystems, so if we add the ```-mount``` (or ```-xdev```) parameter, the search is limited to a single filesystem - exactly what the OP wanted.

Comment: Answers should stand on their own and not depend on other answers.

Comment: The actual question was how to limit **already specified** command to single filesystem only. I answered **precisely that**.